# query action with php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a command that get data in mysql with php and have the follow command to remove a div (can have multiples removes):

```
echo "<div id='".$experience['index_of_form']."'>";
echo "<a href='#remove' id='remove' name='".$experience['index_of_form']."' style='text-align: right; text-decoration: underline;'>Remove</a>
echo "</div>";
```

When I see the output the name is experience1 (example), or experience2. So far so good.

To remove I have this jquery function:

```
$('#remove').live("click", function() {
var name_of_experience = $('#remove').attr("name");
$('#'+name_of_experience+'').remove();
});
```

The problem is if I have a remove link with name experience2 he will remove the div with the name experience1! I dont know why, because when I see in the output, the name of the link is experience2 and not experience1.

Comment: I don't see any problem. http://jsfiddle.net/hmnqr/

Comment: I know, but when I generate the code with php, the remove function does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess it has to do with you assigning the same `ID` to each element. `ID`'s are only to be used once; switch the `ID` with a `CLASS` and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the id `remove` multiple times within the same page, as an ID should be the unique identifier of a single element. jQuery will just take the first one it finds within the DOM. Try use a class instead of an id.

As of jQuery 1.7, `.live()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()`. I also took the liberty to add a minor perf improvement by using `$(this)` instead of a selector when getting the name-value:

```
$('body').on("click", "a.remove", function() {
   var name_of_experience = $(this).attr("name");
   $('#'+name_of_experience).remove();
});
```

Comment: I forgot to tell, i'm using the version "1.6.4/jquery.min.js" so i switch the .on() to .live().. But still does not work. I already switch the ID to CLASS in div and link